# How do I add onclick to a Selz button?

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

I have a Selz button and am trying to figure out how to add an **onclick** to it which will call a tracking function, **onclick**='myfunction()'

I'm at a loss with this particular button.  I have added the **onclick** to other links and buttons, but this one baffles me.  I tried adding the **onclick** after "Buy The Digital Version" but it did not work.

This is the code for the button:

```html
    <script data-selz-t="_selz-btn-default" data-selz-a="modal" data-selz-checkout="true" data-selz-cb="6699cc" data-selz-chbg="ffffff" data-selz-chtx="000000" data-selz-b="http://selz.co/1234$XYZ" data-text="Buy The Digital Version">
        if (typeof _$elz === "undefined") { var _$elz = {}; }
        if (typeof _$elz.b === "undefined") 
        { 
            _$elz.b = { e: document.createElement("script") }; 
            _$elz.b.e.src = "https://selz.com/embed/button;"; 
            document.body.appendChild(_$elz.b.e);
        }
    </script>
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Get the ID or Class of a button from browser in inspect element. And then with that ID or Class you can add js onclick event.

Comment: There is no ID or Class for this since it is loaded from script, or am I missing something?

Comment: But if you see the button in browser inspect element which is loaded from script, you will get the id or class.